# Show that there is no integer polynomial that only outputs prime numbers. (Hint: Suppose that f(a) = p and then consider f(a + p)).

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Show that there is no integer polynomial that only outputs prime numbers. (Hint:
Suppose that f(a) = p and then consider f(a + p)).

I do not actually know how to follow the hint. Could somebody help me? Thanks so much.

Comment: Does $p$ divide $f(a+p)-f(a)$? If so, what can be the possible values of $f(a+p)$? Further, if $f(a+p)$ is prime, then what values can it possibly have? This will help you conclude.

Comment: There are many polynomials with integral coefficients that only output prime numbers. For example, $f(x) = 2$ (constant). ;)

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes#Prime_formulas_and_polynomial_functions).

Comment: It should say "*nonconstant* integer polynomials...."

Answer (score 1):

Say we have a polynomial of degree $N$:
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{N}a_kx^k$$
with $a_N\neq 0$. Now, if we have a prime $p$, then $x^n\equiv (x+p)^n\pmod p$ and hence for all primes $p$ and $x\in\Bbb{N}$:
$$f(x)\equiv f(x+p)\pmod p$$
(This is not only true for primes, but it's what we need.)

Now, suppose $f(a)=p$. Then for all $k\in\Bbb{Z}$, we have:
$$p\mid f(a+pk)$$
So in order for $f$ to be prime for every value, we need $f(a+pk)=p$ for every integer value of $k$. But this is impossible, since $f$ only has degree $N$, so $g(x)=f(x)-p$ can only have $N$ roots.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ p\!:\ f(a+np) \equiv f(a)\equiv 0\ $ by the [Polynomial Congruence Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)